# Create a random dataset for regression analyses (teaching and model testing)

Tags: multiple-regression, dataset, random-variable

I would like to create a random dataset which allows me to conduct regression analyses as realistically as possible (e.g. for teaching, but also to test different models). The analyses I would like to conduct would be simple multivariable regression analyses, e.g.:

$ y = \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2  x_2 \cdots $

The data should be 'random' enough to give realistic results, and ideally should not require a linear relationship (but for example splines).

What I am looking for is a method where I can specify the parameters (including error) of several regression models - and which then creates a dataset with $n$ samples which will give the precified results when using the same models.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what would constitute a "method"?  From one point of view, writing down the regression model *is* a method, which leaves us no actual question to answer.  What are you hoping to see in the answers?

Comment: I tried to clarify the question.

Comment: I cannot write comments, but have a look at the answer (using R) here:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/59064/200663 Edit: the answer there is only concerned with linear regression, but it might give some idea on how to simulate a dataset with splines anyway.

Comment: That is working - but I'm somewhat confused why the script simply adds the noise - shouldn't it multiply the coefficient with the noise?

Comment: No, noise in these models is additive. However, you show a linear regression and then say you want it to be complicated enough to require splines. Perhaps you mean "should not require splines"?

Comment: I would like to use splines in the models - but have have changed the original function to include  3rd degree polynomial and that works well. I would like to use the data to show differences between different approaches and especially show that not all associations are linear.